# Grails database migration - changing previous migrations

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

Unfortunately I have just noticed an issue in one of my previous migrations whereby I specify the baseTableSchemaName and now cannot create a database with an alternative name.
I don't suppose anyone has any advice on how to change these and then clear the checksums in production. While the following;

`grails dbm-clear-checksums`

can be used in dev, for me, grails is not installed in production.

Is there anyway to automate this and worst case, can you simply update the databasechangelog table to set the MD5SUM to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that I've since adopted, it may not be as elegant as I would have liked but might help someone else in a similar situation.

Simply update all of the databasechangelog records and set md5sum = null. New checksums are calculated on next database migration update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of all the details of your problem, especially, the question is how many databasechangelog records need to be fixed. But I can share my experience what I usually did with my application(I use grails 2.5.5).
For example, let's say, we have few migrations which were edited and checksums mismatch. I do the following:

1. Create test database in development environment and synchronise all the migrations with the latests version on it. Thus, in development database you will have correct values of md5sum. The good thing is, those sums are environment independent and rely only on the migrations content itself.
2. Go to production database and manually update records with the correct values taken from development database.
3. Migrations should not have checksum conflicts anymore.

Comment: Tbh, I was looking to try and fix this in a single step, rather than updating individual records. I also use Grails 2.5.5. I actually just went ahead and tested the solution whereby I update all of the databasechangelog records and set md5sum =  null. This worked for me. Is there any reason why you don't employ this simple method of getting past the problem? New checksums are calculated on next database migration update anyway.

Comment: @dre > Is there any reason why you don't employ this simple method of getting past the problem?
It didn't come to my mind actually. Thanks for your result. I will test it next time I have troubles with that :) I do believe you have to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted answer. Your solution is much easier than mine.

Comment: Thanks @Andrej. It wasn't quite what I was looking for but I'll add it anyhow in case hit helps someone else.